# Tailwindcss and react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

trying to use tailwindcss with react

I installed tailwind already but yet cant see its effect in my react code.

Used tailwind documentations yet no changes

created a tailwind.config.js file, did this as well

```
                 @tailwind base;
```

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

Answer (score 2):

First step:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
```

Second step:

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

Third step, paste this in content in `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
```

Fourth step, paste these in your CSS file, then import CSS to your JS or JSX file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) carefully, and do all the steps below:

1. Install Tailwind CSS

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

2. Create `tailwind.config.js` file

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

3. Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

4. Start the `Tailwind CLI` build process

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

**After do all of this, you can use Tailwind’s utility classes in your project**